# Как отрисовать через canvas изогнутые линии со сгибом

Tags: javascript, html, css3, canvas

Не могу найти точную информацию, как правильно реализовать.

Находил информацию только с рисовкой линий, но не объемных фигур.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и озвучил я в комментариях SVG

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 270 280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M36,138 101,138 116,183 75,271 " fill="#295A9E"/>
  <path d="M75,271 196,15 264,15 143,271z" fill="#1B395E"/>
</svg>
```